# Sending email with python email not sent/received

Tags: python, email

Setting up email for a new domain, been able to link support@... to my gmail so I can send/receive emails from it, tested a send and it works nicely.

For python

```
In [13]: server = smtplib.SMTP('mail.kazilynk.com', 587)

In [14]: server.login("no-reply@kazilynk.com", "---------")
Out[14]: (235, 'Authentication succeeded')

In [15]: server.sendmail("no-reply@kazilynk.com", "muiruri.samuel@gmail.com", "Test")
Out[15]: {}
```

it connects, "sends" but no email is ever received nor does it raise an error. I've send multiple different test none have been received. 
Any help debugging this will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the message being caught by the gmail spam filter?

Comment: Wait it takes some time , check junk folder

Comment: **`Racist gmail not allow any operation without header`**

Comment: not in filter or junk folder likely though missing that header is causing it not to work.